# Subtracting a fixed date from a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider

```
In [99]: d = pd.to_datetime({'year':[2016], 'month':[06], 'day':[01]})
In [100]: d1 = pd.to_datetime({'year':[2016], 'month':[01], 'day':[01]})

In [101]:d - d1
Out[101]: 
0   152 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

But when I try to do this for a whole column, it gives me trouble. Consider:

```
df['Age'] = map(lambda x:x - pd.to_datetime({'year':[2016], 'month':[06], 'day':[01]}), df['Manager_DoB'])
```

`df['Manager_Dob']` is a column of datetime objects.
It flags the following error:

`TypeError: can only operate on a datetime with a rhs of a timedelta/DateOffset for addition and subtraction, but the operator [__rsub__] was passed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use map*, you can subtract a Timestamp from a datetime column/Series:

```
In [11]: d = pd.to_datetime({'year':[2016], 'month':[6], 'day':[1]})

In [12]: d
Out[12]:
0   2016-06-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [13]: d[0]  # This is the Timestamp you are actually interested in subtracting
Out[13]: Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00')

In [14]: dates = pd.date_range(start="2016-01-01", periods=4)

In [15]: dates - d[0]
Out[15]: TimedeltaIndex(['-152 days', '-151 days', '-150 days', '-149 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You can get the Timestamp more directly using the constructor:

```
In [21]: pd.Timestamp("2016-06-01")
Out[21]: Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00')
```

**You should never use python's map with pandas, prefer `.apply`.*

Comment: I used the apply method initially, but it gave me the same error. Also I tried `dates - d` and it gave me a row of `NaT` values. But adding the `d[0]` is the solution. That works. I still don't know why it let me perform `dates - d`.

Comment: I also had a problem with the result being a column of `NaT` values and for that specific case I had to subtract `d.iloc[0]`.